# What's the adjectival form of "evangelist"?

Tags: adjectives, derivational-morphology

I have a question about how to write the following:

> 1 Timothy, 2 Timothy, and Titus are commonly known as the "pastoral epistles" because they're allegedly written to pastors. However, the recipients were evangelists ([2 Timothy 4:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%204%3A5&version=NKJV)), which are distinct from pastors ([Ephesians 4:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%204%3A11&version=NKJV)). Therefore, they could more accurately be called the [BLANK] epistles.

The [BLANK] is the adjectival form of *evangelist*, but I don't know what that would be. What's the adjective for *evangelist* as used here? Thanks!

Comment: They could be **evangelic** or [**evangelical**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/evangelical) epistles, since the adjective describes the epistles and not their readers.

Comment: Whether or not Timothy is being addressed as an evangelist here, or being asked to double / fill in, evangelising, while there is a lack of ('fivefold ministry') evangelists and he has to fulfil the role of pastor / teacher, is moot. But certainly the term 'pastoral' is more appropriate than 'evangelistic' here, as the letters discuss primarily issues of Christian living, doctrine and church leadership. The 'evangelical epistles' are usually considered to be Romans, I and IICorinthians, and Galatians.

Comment: (because they address the Good News). See [The Strategic Grasp Of The Bible
By J. Sidlow Baxter](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kM6uDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT113&lpg=PT113&dq=%22evangelical+epistles%22&source=bl&ots=hH18ml8diN&sig=ACfU3U0bmx2qTAqXPHahK2IMdjItu3yjPw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE54rlzKnnAhVqSBUIHeOOD9oQ6AEwB3oECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=%22evangelical%20epistles%22&f=false).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Though the emphasis of this forum is grammatical, not discussing the merit of the example paragraph I cited, can you cite a passage from 2 Timothy that seems more pastoral than evangelistic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about ***[evangelistic:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/evangelistic)***

> - pertaining to evangelists or to preachers of the gospel
> - evangelical

(Dictionary.com)

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I'll go with "evangelistic."

Comment: I'd prefer *evangelist* or *evangelical* over *evangelistic*, which sounds cynical.